# Creating a for-loop that stores values in a new variable

Tags: matlab

I'm quite new to Matlab so excuse me for the basic question. 
I need to make a for-loop that repeats it's self 384 times.

So :

```
for i=1:384
```

I now need the for loop to check if 2 certain variables have the value 1 through 10, and then let them store this in a new variable with that value.
So:

```
if x==1
  somevariable = 1
elseif x== 2
  saomevariable = 2
..
..
..
elseif y = 1
  someothervariable = 1
```

etc etc.

Is there a way to write this more efficient?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. please edit your question to show your actual code. In the current version you iterate on `i` but you check `x` (I guessed it should be `x(i)` or did you calculate `x` previously in the loop?). Try to make a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve (read how to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) )

Answer (score 0):

The first think you can do is:

```
if(x >= 1 && x <= 10)
   somevariable=x;
end
if(y >= 1 && y <= 10)
   someohtervariable=y;
end
```

If you could post more information about "`x`" and "`y`", perhaps your script can be further "improved".

Hope this helps.